# Webdriver kicks the bucket on "find_element"

Tags: element, webdriver

I am using the Ruby interpretation of Webdriver.  Now the webpage I am looking at may or may not contain a certain element.  If it doesn't I would like to look for another element.  However, whenever Webdriver can't find an element it throws an exception.

My question is, can I check to see if the element even exists on the page without littering my code with begin/rescue blocks ?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no. To check if element exists, you have to rescue errors. `find_element` always throw `NoSuchElementError` if element was not found. You can for example take a look at [implementation](https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/blob/master/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb#L35) of `#exists?` method in Watir-WebDriver.

Still, you can use `find_elements` method which will return empty array if not elements were found.

```rb
elements = @browser.find_elements(id: 'doesnt-exist')
if elements.empty?
  # go to the next element
else
  # work with element
  element = elements.first
  element.click
end
```

Comment: thanks for the tip.  Found myself digging through the source late at night and decided to try again tomorrow( today ).  That's kind of weird that they don't have a "has_element" or "element_exists" in the codebase.