# Rescue for ScriptError in Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a written a Code in Selenium Web driver to test the health of the Contact Us page of my web site.

Code is working fine. My further aim is to:

1. Use Rescue (to get error message when this scripts fail. Specifically when some element is not found during execution in the function > "def test_contact_us_screen_shot").

Code for reference.

```
require 'rubygems'
require "selenium-webdriver"
require "test/unit"

class ContactUsScreenShot < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def setup
    @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
    @base_url = "http://www.mycompany.com"
    @driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 30
    @verification_errors = []
  end

  def teardown
    @driver.quit
    assert_equal [], @verification_errors
  end

  def test_contact_us_screen_shot
    @driver.get(@base_url + "/contact_us")
    #This method will take screenshot and  save it in the same folder from where script is executed.
    @driver.save_screenshot("./screen1.png")
    puts "screen shot taken"
    assert_equal "mycompany.com - Discuss your requirements to Outsource Software Product Development, Offshore Software Testing,", @driver.title
    @driver.find_element(:id, "compan").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "company").send_keys "My Company"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "first_name").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "first_name").send_keys "Mrityunjay"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "last_name").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "last_name").send_keys "Chauhan"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "email").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "email").send_keys "mrityunjay@gmail.com"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "phone1").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "phone1").send_keys "9999999999"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "addr1").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "addr1").send_keys "306 Office Address"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "addr2").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "addr2").send_keys "Office Address"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "city").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "city").send_keys "Dehradun"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "state").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "state").send_keys "UK"
    Selenium::WebDriver::Support::Select.new(@driver.find_element(:id, "country")).select_by(:text, "India")
    @driver.find_element(:id, "zip").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "zip").send_keys "248001"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "website").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "website").send_keys "http://www.mycompany.com"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "comments").clear
    @driver.find_element(:id, "comments").send_keys "This is the Testing Script for Contact Us page. Please Ignore.\nThanks,\nMrityunjay Chauhan"
    @driver.find_element(:name, "submit").click
    assert_equal "mycompany.com - Discuss your requirements to Outsource Software Product Development, Offshore Software Testing,", @driver.title
    begin
      rescue Exception => e
      puts e.message
      @driver.save_screenshot("./error1.png")
  end
  puts "I am Here"
    end

   def element_present?(how, what)
    @driver.find_element(how, what)
    true
  rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError
    false
  end

  def verify(&blk)
    yield
  rescue Test::Unit::AssertionFailedError => ex
    @verification_errors << ex
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Following Rescue code is working fine in my code...

```
rescue Exception => e
        puts e.message
        puts "Element Not Found"
        @driver.save_screenshot("./Test-Results/Contact_Us_Error.png")
        puts "I am Here"
    end #rescue
```

In rescue we can trace the errors by using Log. For this we have to generated log file. Code is given below:

First define log at the start of your code as:

```
# Here I have created a log file in my "Test-Result" folder
$log = Logger.new('./Test-Results/logfile.log')
```

Next, we will move the error message to our log file using code given below:

```
rescue Exception => e
            $log.error "This is the Error occurred when Element/s not found: #{e}"
            @driver.save_screenshot("./Test-Results/Contact_Us_Error.png")
            puts "I am Here"
        end #rescue
```

Log will be something like this:
E, [2012-06-04T16:03:44.546875 #796] ERROR -- : Error in Elements when not found!: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"compan"}

Answer (score 1):

[Here is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527702/webdriver-kicks-the-bucket-on-find-element) -- just use "find_elements" instead which gives an empty array instead of throwing an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this

```
begin
    @driver.find_element(:name, "submit") 
rescue
    @driver.save_screenshot("Submit_button_not_present.png")
    assert_match "true","false","Your error message"
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried the above code in my script and got following error:

1) Failure:
test_contact_us_screen_shot(ContactUsScreenShot) [Contact-us-ScreenShot.rb:56]:

My error message.

<"false"> expected to be =~

</true/>.

Comment: On executing the script with rescue as given below, things worked properly.

begin


      rescue Exception => e


      puts e.message


      @driver.save_screenshot("./error1.png")


  end

Comment: so did it work ? If it did help you, please mark this as your answer.

Comment: Thanks Guys for putting up your suggestions... After putting some efforts I was able to make my code working. The same I have mentioned in my answer. Hope this will help people out here...